# Intellisense not working on shared ressources files between projects (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015, shared-resource

I'm working on a asp.net MVC solution.

I have created a common resources folder in my solution. The goal is to use the same resources files in different projects.

To do this, I followed this great tutorial :

https://www.opten.ch/blog/2015/02/17/sharing-resources-between-projects-in-a-visual-studio-solution/

It works, I can build my code but no files added to the shared project have intellisense. Moreover there is some code underlined in red. (In particular with the .cshtml file)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you added a reference to the shared project?

Comment: How can do this? The common resources folder is not a "project", it is a folder.